# How AWS Lambda and AWS Fargate work for Spring Boot Web Application?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

Assume I have a simple Spring Boot Hello World Microservice proving a single endpoint:

GET http://hostname/hello?name=name

and it gives text response: Hello name

This Spring Boot app is deployed as fat executable jar with embedded tomcat webserv.er, so that when it is launched it is always running tomcat server waiting for GET request.

When I deploy this app in AWS Lambda, AWS will charge me only when it is processing a GET request and not charge me when it is idle i.e. not processing GET request but waiting for GET requests?

The same question when the app is deployed as Docker container in AWS ECS Fargate or AWS EKS Fargate.

What would be the approximate AWS Lambda and AWS Fargate charges per day when 1000 GET requests are made per day? Just rough approximation.

Comment: Your code needs to be Lambda-compatible which an embedded web server isn't so no - you won't even be able to deploy it. As a container, you will pay fo the instance running, not per request.

Comment: You can indeed deploy the application on Lambda [as a Docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) but it would be useless as each request would take forever to complete since starting a Spring Boot app in a Tomcat server takes quite some time given this situation. I don't know if some elaborate scheme to keep the Lambda warm would help but then you'd be looking at an overhead of many requests for each "real" request.

Answer (score 0):

Working out the charges for a Spring Boot app running on Lambda is actually not that hard. First, you need to work out how you're going to deploy it there. There are a few ways.

1. There's a [quick start](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot2) from AWS itself. It's really simple, only a few changes to make in your app, and you can do a 1-line deployment with their SAM CLI. The problem is the cold starts. Your app is going to go cold after some time (AWS won't tell you how long that is. [This article](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-long-does-aws-lambda-keep-your-idle-functions-around-before-a-cold-start) from 2017 has more info). If it needs to startup to serve every request, that could be 20 seconds or even multiple minutes added to your response time. If you're doing some kind of batch jobs maybe this is ok, but in most cases response times of 20 seconds plus is probably going to be a no-go. In your case, with 1000 requests/day, if they are evenly spaced you would be fine because your app would never go cold. If they're grouped, you might need option 2.
2. [Kotless](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotless) from JetBrains is a great option for Kotlin. Again it's only a few small changes to your app and you're deployed on Lambda. Kotless has a built-in autoWarm option, which means your app is pinged every 5 minutes to stay warm so no more cold starts (you can change that to whatever frequency you want). It adds an extra cost but that cost is seriously **tiny**.

#### Pricing

For option 1, if you take your 10,000 requests/day, that's 300,000/month. Using region US East, response time 400ms, and 1500MB (should be plenty), if you haven't used up your Lambda free tier, that will cost $0.00. Even if you have used your free tier, that's $2.99. Even with option 2, we add ~8000 requests for the auto warming, which adds only a few cents to your monthly bill.

In future Spring Native could also be a great option. As of now I've found it too immature, but that way you can forget about cold starts. So overall, Spring Boot on Lambda seems crazy considering how "heavy" it is but actually, it could be a really cheap option for you, especially if you use DynamoDB for your persistence layer and use the free tier there too.

*All prices from the official AWS cost calculator